# Open Dialog defaulting to specified network path (not drive)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to assign my open dialog box to default to a specific folder on the network.  Let's use the path:

```
\\test\yes\no\
```

The code below doesn't work, but also doesn't error out.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectory _
Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "SetCurrentDirectoryA" ( _
ByVal lpPathName As String) _
As Long

SetCurrentDirectory "\\test\yes\no\"
```

I've seen a few ways people are doing this, but nothing seems to be working for me.  I'm using excel 2010 if that helps.

My directory code:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    SetCurrentDirectory "\\test\yes\no\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then MsgBox "No folder selected! Exiting script.": Exit Sub
    myDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With

    MsgBox "Please choose the folder."
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        '*********************************************************************************************
    'Check for .xls cutsheets; open one at a time with a loop until all file data has been copied
    '*********************************************************************************************
    folderPath = myDir
        If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
        Do While fileName <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wbkCS = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)
```

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit office ?  http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

Comment: I wondered that too, but it's 32-bit.

Comment: So you do get the open file dialog but the folder is not the one specified by SetCurrentDirectory?

Comment: @Kim that is correct.  It's whatever the last directory I opened was.

Comment: `SetCurrentDirectory` works for me on Office 2003 and Office 2013 provided the share exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not either get it to work using `Application.FileDialog` and `SetCurrentDirectory`. However, using the `InitialFileName` property and setting it to `"\\test\yes\no\"` (i.e. only specifying a path) does work.

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = "\\test\yes\no\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then MsgBox "No folder selected! Exiting script.": Exit Sub
        myDir = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

Comment: I'll try this Kim when I get a minute; it's still not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to open a dialog box using the following:

```
Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectory _
Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "SetCurrentDirectoryA" ( _
ByVal lpPathName As String) _
As Long


Sub OpenDialogInNetworkPath()
    SetCurrentDirectory "\\test\yes\no\"
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a file to import", _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls (*.xls),")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen
End Sub
```

Does this help? Can you please post the full macro?

Comment: There is one other detail, which I'll post the code.  I have the script cycling through all the files in the folder, but I don't know how that would impact the directory piece?

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be working now all of a sudden?  There's something wacky going on here because I'm running into UNC issues with mapped drives.  So, I'm going to call it a day and mark this as solved.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad to help. I coldn't help but notice that you accepted it and then unaccepted it. Is this question answered or not? I'd be happy to continue helping.

Comment: ACK... wow, I am full of failure today.  Actually it was Kim's suggestion below that got me working.  I don't know why it was that easy, but it works after testing multiple ways of opening.

Comment: Hahaha no problem, I'm glad at least someone managed to get things working for you! Good luck with the rest of your project.